# Apache Mac WebSharing not working

Tags: mac

I'm new to Mac and I'm trying to setup a simple webserver.  I have configured apache, turned on websharing and turned off the firewall.  I can connect to the ip address locally via a web browser but can't establish a connection to port 80 via a web browser or telnet from any other system.  It's OS version 10.7.4.  Is there anything else that may be blocking port 80 on in OSX that I'm unaware of?
\

Comment: Ok, so I was rebooting the mac and for a brief moment I was able to connect to port 80 from another system.  But after the mac was fully restarted I was back to no access.  It seems like something else is starting up that eventually blocks that port... but the firewall is disabled.  Strange.

Comment: another thought, I configured apache manually by editing the httpd.conf file.  I'm not sure how that meshes with Web Sharing.

Comment: So: stash that edited file somewhere, then try web sharing with the original httpd.conf file.  This test should suggest whether the problem is with the edit or with something else.